# On the asymptotic behaviour of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{\zeta(ns)}{n}+\frac{s}{1-ns}\right )$ near $s=0$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics, riemann-zeta-function

I am interested in determining the behaviour of the the series/function

$$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{\zeta(ns)}{n}+\frac{s}{1-ns}\right )$$

near $s=0$. It is clear that $f(0)$ is undefined. However, $f(s)$ is well-defined for all complex variables $s$ with $\mathrm{Re}(s)>0.$

All "classical" methods have failed me; Expanding $\zeta(ns)$ near $ns=0$ as a finite number of terms in the Laurent series for $\zeta$ results in an divergent overall sum. I have also tried writing the sum as a partial sum and taking the limit but to no avail.

**NOTE:** I was, at first, only looking for a hint. But since the question seems to be non-trivial, I would like to rigorously prove the expansion of the aforementioned series.

@Carlo Beenakker has in [his answer to this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462745/510524) conjectured the expansion

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \log x+\mathcal{O}(1).$$

Now let $x$ be a real variable with $0<x \leq 1$. We can then write $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x),$ where

$$f_1(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\lceil \frac{1}{x}\rceil} \left ( \frac{\zeta(nx)}{n}+\frac{x}{1-nx}\right )$$

and

$$f_2(s)=\sum_{n=\lceil \frac{1}{x}\rceil+1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{\zeta(nx)}{n}+\frac{x}{1-nx}\right ).$$

Indeed, $f_1(x)$ does probably have the desired asymptotic expansion

$$f_1(x)=\frac{1}{2} \log x -\frac{\gamma}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x).$$

Thus, I think it is, after proving this, sufficient to prove that $f_2(x)=\mathcal{O}(1)$.

**Further tasks:**

1.) Proving the asymptotic expansion of $f_1(x)$.

2.) Explicitly evaluating the following limit:

$$\lim_{s \rightarrow 0} f_2(x)= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sum_{n=\lceil \frac{1}{x}\rceil+1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{\zeta(nx)}{n}+\frac{x}{1-nx}\right ).$$

**Appendix:**

On the request of @Stropple, I prove the following proposition:

**Proposition**. $f$ is a complex-valued function on the right half-plane $ \left \{s \in \mathbb{C} : \mathrm{Re}(s) > 0  \right \}.$

*Proof*. Let $s \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\mathrm{Re}(s)>0$. Assume $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1$. Upon making use of the inequality

$$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, \ \mathrm{Re}(z)>1: \left | \frac{\zeta(z)}{z}+\frac{1}{1-z} \right | \leq \frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}(z)(\mathrm{Re}(z)-1)},$$

we have

$$\left |f(s) \right | = \left |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s \left ( \frac{\zeta(ns)}{ns}+\frac{1}{1-ns} \right) \right | \leq \left | s \right | \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left |\frac{\zeta(ns)}{ns}+\frac{1}{1-ns} \right | \leq \left | s \right | \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}(ns)(\mathrm{Re}(ns)-1)}=-\frac{\left |s \right| \left(\gamma+\psi \left ( 1-\frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}(s)} \right ) \right)}{\mathrm{Re}(s)}$$

where $\psi$ is the digamma function. By the choice of $s$, the resulting upper bound is finite.

Assume now $0 < \mathrm{Re}(s) \leq 1$. Then, we can write

$$\left |f(s) \right| = \left |f_1(\mathrm{Re}(s))+f_2(\mathrm{Re}(s)) \right| \leq \left |f_1(\mathrm{Re}(s)) \right|+\left |f_2(\mathrm{Re}(s)) \right|$$

If $\mathrm{Re}(s) \notin \left \{\frac{1}{k} : k \in \mathbb{N}  \right \}$, it is clear that $\left | f_1(\mathrm{Re}(s)) \right|$ is finite. However, even when $\mathrm{Re}(s)=\frac{1}{k}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\left | f_1(\mathrm{Re}(s)) \right|$ is finite (the term $n=k$ in the definition of $f_1$ is taken in the sense of a limit). It is thus sufficient to bound $\left |f_2(\mathrm{Re}(s)) \right|$. By a similar argument, we have

$$\left |f_2(\mathrm{Re}(s)) \right|=\left |s \sum_{n=\lceil \frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}(s)}\rceil+1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{\zeta(ns)}{ns}+\frac{1}{1-ns}\right ) \right| \leq \left | s \right| \sum_{n=\lceil \frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}(s)}\rceil+1}^{\infty} \left | \frac{\zeta(ns)}{ns}+\frac{1}{1-ns}\right| \leq \left | s \right| \sum_{n=\lceil \frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}(s)}\rceil+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}(ns)(\mathrm{Re}(ns)-1)} \leq \frac{\left | s \right|  \left (\psi \left ( \left \lceil \frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}(s)} \right \rceil +1 \right )-\psi \left (\lceil \frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}(s)}\rceil+1-\frac{1}{\mathrm{Re}(s)} \right ) \right )}{\mathrm{Re}(s)}.$$

By the choice of $s$, the resulting upper bound is finite. $\blacksquare$

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why (or in what sense) do you think the infinite sum on $n$ converges?  As you observe, each term looks like $-1/2n +O(s)$.

Comment: It, of course, diverges at $s=0$.

Comment: Why should it converge anywhere near $s=0$?

Comment: It should converge for all $s$ with $\mathrm{Re}(s)>0$. The only potentially problematic inputs would be of the form $s=\frac{1}{k}, k \in \mathbb{N}$, but it still converges (the term $n=k$ in the sum should be taken as a limit).

Comment: What does "should converge" mean?  The question of convergence has nothing to do with 'problematic inputs'.

Comment: I wasn’t implying that because there are no problematic inputs, that the series converges. I can, if needed, include a proof that the series converges.

Comment: Yes, the proof please.

Comment: In my post below, I confirm the claimed approximation for $f(s)$.

Comment: @Stopple I have added the requested proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Proposition.** The following approximation holds true:
$$f(s)=\frac{1}{2}\log s+O(1),\qquad s\in(0,1).$$
**Proof.** Following Carlo Benakker, we remark that
$$\zeta(s)+\frac{s}{1-s}=-\frac{1}{2}+O(s),\qquad |s|<2.$$
Indeed, the left-hand side is an entire function with value $-1/2$ at $s=0$. Using this approximation, we obtain for $s\in(0,1)$ that
$$\begin{align*}
f_1(s)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\lceil 1/s\rceil} \left (-\frac{1}{2n}+O(s)\right )\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\lceil 1/s\rceil}\frac{1}{n}+O(1)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\log s+O(1).
\end{align*}$$
It remains to show that $f_2(s)$ is bounded for $s\in(0,1)$. To see this, we use the integral representation
$$\zeta(s)+\frac{s}{1-s}=-s\int_1^\infty\{u\}u^{-s-1}du,\qquad \Re s>0,$$
which yields that
$$f_2(s)=-s\sum_{n=\lceil 1/s\rceil+1}^{\infty} \int_1^\infty\{u\}u^{-ns-1}du,\qquad \Re s>0.$$
By Fubini's theorem, we can interchange the summation and the integration, so that
$$f_2(s)=-s\int_1^\infty\frac{\{u\}}{u^{1+s\lceil 1/s\rceil}(u^s-1)}\,du,\qquad \Re s>0.$$
Assume now that $s\in(0,1)$. Then $s\lceil 1/s\rceil \geq 1$, and $u^s-1>s\log u$ for all $u>1$, whence
$$|f_2(s)|\leq \int_1^\infty\frac{\{u\}}{u^{2}\log u}\,du,\qquad s\in(0,1).$$
The last integral converges, and it is independent of $s$, hence we are done.

In fact, this upper bound is optimal:

**Added.** For $s\to 0+$, we have that $s\lceil 1/s \rceil \to 1$, and $(u^s-1)/s\to\log u$ for all $u>1$, hence Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem yields
$$\lim_{s\to 0+}f_2(s)=-\int_1^\infty\frac{\{u\}}{u^2\log u}\,du.$$

Comment: Wonderful argument! So, now we know that $f_1(s)=\frac{1}{2} \log s + \mathcal{O}(1)$ and that $f_2(s)=\mathcal{O}(1)$. But, can we actually evaluate $C=\lim_{s \rightarrow 0} f_2(s)$? And, if so, can we claim right away that $f_2(s)=C+\mathcal{O}(s)$?. That would be of great help to me!

Comment: @TianVlašić See my "Added" section.

Comment: @TianVlašić We cannot claim right away that $f_2(s)=C+O(s)$. I gave you the value of $C$. Now you can write $f_2(s)-C$ as a single integral over the line $u>1$, and analyze that integral similarly as I analyzed the original integral. I am lazy to work this out, but I am confident that $f_2(s)=C+O(s)$ will follow. I guess you will need to use the second order Taylor expansion of $u^s-1$ around $s=0$.

Comment: I think this is enough for me to work the rest out by myself. Thank you once again!

Comment: @TianVlašić Great. BTW your questions get greater visibility if you add a high-level tag to it. I added nt.number-theory and cv.complex-variables to your post.

Comment: Sounds good to me :)

Comment: @TianVlašić The integral on $(1,250)$ exceeds $3/4$. You can check this with SAGE using the command numerical_integral.

Comment: I am not sure. For some upper bounds, it exceeds $\frac{3}{4}$, for others it is smaller than $\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Try the command `numerical_integral(frac(u)/(u*u*log(u)),1,250,max_points=10000)` in SAGE. Of course you need a sufficiently long interval like $(1,250)$ to have an integral exceeding $3/4$.

Comment: a question: because the logarithm increases so slowly, the $\tfrac{1}{2}\log s$ asymptotics needs the ${\cal O}(1)$ term for accuracy; numerics suggests it's $-1$; I have not succeeded in calculating it, can you?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Well, there are two constants here: $f_1(s)=\frac{1}{2}\log s+c_1+o(1)$ and $f_2(s)=c_2+o(1)$. I gave $c_2$ in the "Added" section in the form of an integral, while calculating $c_1$ should be straightforward from the Laurent coefficients of $\zeta(s)$ around $s=1$. Your question boils down to $c_1+c_2=-1$. If this is true, then it is probably nontrivial to prove it. At any rate, I cannot devote time to this question now.

Comment: @GHfromMO I have previously defined functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ in terms of the floor function. However, it is much more sensible to define them in terms of the ceiling function. I would be grateful if you could adjust your answer to these new definitions. I am very sorry for the inconvenience. However, it should not be difficult or drastically different from what you've already been able to do.

Comment: @TianVlašić I am sorry, but I don't have time for this. On the other hand, please don't change questions that have been answered. It is against the etiquette of this site. If needed, please open a new question.

Comment: While I respect that you might not have time for this, I note the fact that replacing the floor function with the ceiling function keeps every single one of your arguments correct. Can you possibly simply do that?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker The constant term in the asymptotic expansion of $f(s)-\log s$ takes the form $\frac{\gamma}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \log{2\pi}-\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\left \{ u \right \}}{u^{2} \log u} du \approx -0.88$.

Comment: @TianVlašić Feel free to update my post.

Comment: @GHfromMO Done.

Comment: $\int_1^\infty\frac{\{u\}}{u^2\log u}du=0.75036751215075390992131242125469306130...$

Answer (score 4):

We seek the small-$s$ asymptotics of the sum
$$f(s)=s\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(ns),\;\;g(x)=\frac{\zeta(x)}{x}+\frac{1}{1-x}.$$
First note that
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\sum_{n=\lfloor{2/s}\rfloor+1}^\infty sg(ns)=\int_2^\infty g(x)\,dx=-0.48,$$
hence the summation range $n\gtrsim 2/s$ contributes an amount of order ${\cal O}(1)$ to $f(s)$.
For $n\lesssim 2/s$ you can expand
$$\frac{\zeta(ns)}{n}+\frac{s}{1-ns}=\frac{-1}{2 n}+{\cal O}(s),$$
and sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor 2/s\rfloor}\frac{-1}{2 n}=\tfrac{1}{2}\ln s +{\cal O}(1),$$
resulting in
$$f(s)=\tfrac{1}{2}\ln s+{\cal O}(1).$$
A numerical evaluation confirms this is the correct asymptotics:

[image]

Blue is the numerically evaluated sum, as a function of real $s$, red is $\tfrac{1}{2}\ln s-1$ on a log-linear scale; the slopes agree.

For complex $s$ (with $\operatorname{Re}s>0$) the absolute value governs the asymptotics, $|f(s)|\rightarrow \tfrac{1}{2}\ln|1/s|+{\cal O}(1)$. The plot below shows $|f(s e^{i\pi/4})|$ (blue) and $1+\tfrac{1}{2}\ln |1/s|$ (red), again with good correspondence.

[image]

Comment: To make this formal, I suggest, as a starting point, to consider the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\left \lfloor \frac{1}{s} \right \rfloor}\frac{-1}{2n}$.

Comment: I added the case of complex $s$, with the $\tfrac{1}{2}\ln|1/s|$ asyptotics.

Comment: That's great, but I think it is much wiser to focus on the restriction $s>0$.

Comment: I have added the evaluation of the large-$n$ range, where the sum can be replaced by the integral to leading order in $s$.

Comment: How do we know the relation $\lim_{s \rightarrow 0}\sum_{n=\lfloor \frac{2}{s} \rfloor +1}^{\infty} s g(ns)=\int_{2}^{\infty} g(t) dt$?

Comment: isn't this just the Riemann sum representation of the integral?

Comment: Not quite. At least it is not obvious.